# spaCy 'IS_SPACE' flag doesn't work

Tags: spacy

Been trying to match something like '$125.00/share' on spaCy using its rule-based matching like mentioned here https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/882. However, when trying out

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

doc = nlp(u'$125.00/share, $ 125 / share, $ 125.00 / share, $ 125 . 00 / share')

token_pattern = [{'NORM': '$'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'ORTH': '.', 'OP': '?'}, 
             {'IS_DIGIT': True, 'OP': '?'}, {'ORTH': '/'}, {'LOWER': 'share'}]

def matched_pattern (matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    span = doc[start: end]
    print ('matched!', span)

matcher.add('SharePrice', matched_pattern, token_pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)
```

I get back,

('matched!', $ 125 / share)
('matched!', $ 125 . 00 / share)

Instead, I want to match patterns like '$125.00/share' without the spaces in between. On trying,

```
 token_pattern = [{'NORM': '$'}, {'IS_SPACE': False}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'IS_SPACE': False},{'ORTH': '.', 'OP': '?'}, {'IS_SPACE': False}, 
             {'IS_DIGIT': True, 'OP': '?'}, {'IS_SPACE': False}, {'ORTH': '/'}, {'IS_SPACE': False}, {'LOWER': 'share'}]
```

My expression doesn't match any pattern. Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that each dictionary in the match pattern describes an *actual, existing token* – so `{'IS_SPACE': False}` will match any token that is not a whitespace character (for example, a token with the text "dog" or "123" or anything, really). There is no way for the matcher to match on the *absence of a token*.

I just tried your example and by default, spaCy's tokenizer splits "$125.00/share" into only two tokens: `['$', '125.00/share']`. As the matcher steps through the tokens, it won't match, as it's looking for a currency symbol + a non-space character + a digit + a bunch of other tokens.

So in order to match on more specific parts of the token "125.00/share" – like the number, the forward slash and "share" – you'll have to make sure that spaCy splits those into separate tokens. You can do this by [customising the tokenization rules](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers) and adding a new infix rule that splits tokens on `/` characters. This will result in "$125.00/share" → `['$', '125.00', '/', 'share']`, which will be matched by your pattern.

Btw, some background on whitespace tokens: During tokenization, spaCy splits tokens on single whitespace characters. Those characters won't be available as individual tokens (but to make sure that no information is lost, they can be accessed via the `.text_with_ws_` attribute). However, if there is more than one whitespace character present, spaCy will preserve those as tokens, which will return `True` for `IS_SPACE`. All other tokens will return `False` for `IS_SPACE`.